# Suddenly I got too many error in Eclipse

Tags: android

Just yesterday my app was working fine and everything is good with no error , just today I open e clips then suddenly I found to many error everywhere after some search I found that In "Windows" > "Preferences" > "Android" > "Lint Error Checking":  I need to change something to warning But I have to many different error that suddenly show in all my app . And there support lib

Anyway I go to "Windows" > "Preferences" > "Android" > "Lint Error Checking":

Then you choose ignore all then I run my app its work fine, but I don't think this is good

1. > Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is
   >   horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children where at least one
   >   has layout_width="match_parent"`
2. this error in abc_search_dropdown_light.xml and abc_search_dropdown_dark.xml

   > in `<stroke android:width="2dp" color="#A00080FF"/>`  Attribute is missing the Android
   >    namespace prefix
3. Class referenced in the manifest, finaltest.example.finaltest.Test, was not found in the project or the libraries
4. Multiple annotations found at this line:

   > - "common_google_play_services_notification_needs_update_title" is not translated in  "be"  (Belarusian)
   > - The resource R.string.common_google_play_services_notification_needs_update_title
   >     appears to be unused
5. Multiple annotations found at this line:

   > - The resource R.string.wallet_buy_button_place_holder appears to be unused
   > - "wallet_buy_button_place_holder" is not translated in "af" (Afrikaans), "am" (Amharic), "ar" (Arabic), 
   >     "be" (Belarusian), "bg" (Bulgarian), "ca" (Catalan), "cs" (Czech), "da" (Danish), "de" (German), "el" (Greek), "en-
   >     rGB" (English: United Kingdom), "en-rIN" (English: India), "et-rEE" (Estonian: Estonia), "fa" (Persian), 
   >     "fi" (Finnish), "fr" (French), "fr-rCA" (French: Canada), "hi" (Hindi), "hr" (Croatian), "hu" (Hungarian), "hy-
   >     rAM" (Armenian: Armenia), "in" (Indonesian), "it" (Italian), "iw" (Hebrew), "ja" (Japanese), "ka-rGE" (Georgian: 
   >     Georgia), "km-rKH" (Khmer: Cambodia), "ko" (Korean), "lo-rLA" (Lao: Lao People's Democratic Republic), 
   >     "lt" (Lithuanian), "lv" (Latvian), "mn-rMN" (Mongolian: Mongolia), "ms-rMY" (Malay: Malaysia), 
   >     "nb" (Norwegian Bokmål), "nl" (Dutch), "pl" (Polish), "pt" (Portuguese), "pt-rBR" (Portuguese: Brazil), "pt-
   >     rPT" (Portuguese: Portugal), "ro" (Romanian), "ru" (Russian), "sk" (Slovak), "sl" (Slovene), "sr" (Serbian), 
   >     "sv" (Swedish), "sw" (Swahili), "th" (Thai), "tl" (Tagalog), "tr" (Turkish), "uk" (Ukrainian), "vi" (Vietnamese), "zh-
   >     rCN" (Chinese: China), "zh-rHK" (Chinese: Hong Kong), "zh-rTW" (Chinese: Taiwan, Province of China), 
   >     "zu" (Zulu)
6. Multiple annotations found at this line:

   > - The resource R.string.auth_client_needs_update_title appears to be unused
   > - "auth_client_needs_update_title" is translated here but not found in

Comment: What are the "Many Error" in eclipse? Please provide the details of the error.

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project once?

Comment: i edit my question . i got these error everywhere and more

Comment: Have you kept all your strings.xml file in different languages folder? If no, then please do that.

Comment: i don't get it what u mean , and why this happens suddenly i never change anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Application has strings that has to be translated to other languages. You have not translated all the strings to the languages that your app supports.

**Solutions :**

1. If you wish to support the languages that are mentioned in the error message, they you need to add translated string.xml file to res folder.
2. If you do not want to a string to be translated then go to`Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking`

Now under Category Correctness:Messages look for MissingTranslations and change its Severity from Fatal to Warning or Ignore type.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Project > Clean...

Then Go to your Project Folder.Right Click and Press Build Project.